# use a message from a json object in sweetalert2

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, sweetalert2

I use sweetalert2 and usually I use this code:

```
Swal.fire('my custom title','my custom message','info);
```

and this works fine.
I want to parametrize the message picking up one message from a json. So I built the following:

```
var messages={
  margine: "Il margine è la somma del margine dei mesi precendenti e del margine per mese del mese attuale.", 
  margine_mese: "Il margine per mese è calcolato come differenza tra le entrate del mese e le uscite del mese stesso, senza tenere conto di quanto avvenuto in precedenza",
  radio_cassa: "Il budget per cassa calcola i movimenti nella data in cui creano un movimento di entrata o uscita. I movimenti della carta di credito sono considerati nel mese in cui il relativo saldo viene addebitato in banca", 
  radio_competenza: "Il budget per competenza calcola i movimenti nella data di esecuzione. I movimenti della carta di credito saranno considerati nel mese in cui sono effettuati"
}
```

and my code becomes:

```js
var messages = {
  margine: "Il margine è la somma del margine dei mesi precendenti e del margine per mese del mese attuale.",
  margine_mese: "Il margine per mese è calcolato come differenza tra le entrate del mese e le uscite del mese stesso, senza tenere conto di quanto avvenuto in precedenza",
  radio_cassa: "Il budget per cassa calcola i movimenti nella data in cui creano un movimento di entrata o uscita. I movimenti della carta di credito sono considerati nel mese in cui il relativo saldo viene addebitato in banca",
  radio_competenza: "Il budget per competenza calcola i movimenti nella data di esecuzione. I movimenti della carta di credito saranno considerati nel mese in cui sono effettuati"
}

$('#myButton').click(function() {
  var what = $(this).data('value');
  console.log(what);
  Swal.fire('Info', messages.what, 'info');
  console.log(messages.what);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/sweetalert2@10"></script>

<button id="myButton" data-value="message">Click me</button>
```

I identify correctly what message should I print but I cannot return the corresponding value and print it as message. What is wrong in my code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To access the property of an object using a variable holding its name you need to use bracket notation.

Also note that the `data` attribute value of `message` doesn't match any property in the demo object. In the example I've corrected that error in your HTML.

```js
var messages = {
  margine: "Il margine è la somma del margine dei mesi precendenti e del margine per mese del mese attuale.",
  margine_mese: "Il margine per mese è calcolato come differenza tra le entrate del mese e le uscite del mese stesso, senza tenere conto di quanto avvenuto in precedenza",
  radio_cassa: "Il budget per cassa calcola i movimenti nella data in cui creano un movimento di entrata o uscita. I movimenti della carta di credito sono considerati nel mese in cui il relativo saldo viene addebitato in banca",
  radio_competenza: "Il budget per competenza calcola i movimenti nella data di esecuzione. I movimenti della carta di credito saranno considerati nel mese in cui sono effettuati"
}

$('#myButton').click(function() {
  var what = $(this).data('value');
  Swal.fire('Info', messages[what], 'info');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/sweetalert2@10"></script>
<button id="myButton" data-value="margine">Click me</button> <!-- eg. 'margine' not 'message' -->
```

Comment: the mismatch is a typo, thanks for fixing. The point is: messages is coming from PHP with a `json_encode`. Is this returning a javascript object to convert in json with `json.stringify`? I'd expect json_encode to return a valid json directly!